# Trigger copying of data from mysql Db to MongoDb or any Nosql Db

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is there any way to trigger the copying of data from mysql db to Nosql Db(Like MongoDb) in real time?
It should happen as soon data is updated in mysql db. Sructure wouldnt be same for both the Db's, so replications may not work in this scenario.

Comment: If you are asking how to write a "trigger" when data is updated in your mysql database, then you managed to choose all the wrong tags. You should have tagged with [tag:mysql] instead.

Comment: @BlakesSeven done thanks